# ¿Porque mi aplicacion de Android no se conecta correctamente a la Base de Datos?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una app en Android Studio y da error al hacer la conexión con la base de datos remota (sé que da error ahí porque lo captura el catch y no pasa de esa línea al correr el programa). 
Mí problema es que no encuentro donde está el fallo, aunque imagino que será algo relacionado con la ip del servidor donde tengo la base de datos. He probado con la ip puesta con números, con letras, he mirado que el puerto esté bien y varias cosas más.

Adjunto el código de *Java*:

```
Button btn;
EditText et;
Connection con;
String prueba, un, pass, db, ip;
Statement stt;
TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //ip = "145.14.144.52";
    t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    db = "id3001279_unasproofs";
    ip = "jdbc:mysql://000webhost.com:3306/"+db;
    un = "id3001279_unasproofs";
    pass = "******";

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            prueba = et.getText().toString();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        //.newInstance();
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(ip, un, pass);
                stt = con.createStatement();
                String query = "INSERT INTO txumino VALUES(" +et.getText().toString() + ");";
                ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(query);
            }catch (Exception e){
                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

La contraseña la he puesto con "*" por la seguridad de mi base de datos.
La misma base de datos tiene una única tabla llamada txumino donde hay una columna que es VARCHAR.

Por último añadir que las interfaces son simples. Es un EditText con un boton debajo que lo que haría sería insertar en la base de datos el valor metido en ese campo (EditText).

Error de Logcat:
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Saludos.

Comment: Has revisado cual es el mensaje de error en el LogCat, es importante el uso del LogCat

Comment: Lo acabo de revisar y da un error que no acabo de entender: 
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Comment: Lo que indicas me parece que es solo un mensaje de debug ( por la letra "D/") del sistema, revisa el texto en rojo o donde diga "Caused by..."

Comment: No pone nada de eso por ningún lado

Comment: Deberías imprimir el mensaje de la excepción e del try/catch y a ver si dice algo más .... y por otro lado, has probado a conectar desde algún otro cliente? Es decir, tienes claro que los puertos están abiertos etc?

Comment: intenta conectarte a tu WS por otro medio ... por otro lado no seria mejor realizarlo mediante php-aynctask por ejemplo ... después solo haces referencia a tu php desde android studio

Comment: te recomiendo que para obtener datos de tu bd no te conectes directamente a la bd , desarrolla algun servicio de APi Rest, con respecto a tu errores  el error más común suele ser que que tu IP publica (la ip desde donde ejecutas la aplicación) no tiene permisos en el servidor para conectarse a la BD